# How can I fix the pygame error appearing when initializing mixer?

Tags: python, audio, pygame, libraries

I've had this problem when using pygame's mixer. I've tried everything on the internet (re-installing libSDL etc.) but no solution came up and fixed the issue. The issue is :

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/filepath/filename.py", line 4, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.error: No available audio device
```

The first errors are not important, they do not affect the program (I believe so, but if anyone knows how to get rid of these, I would also really appreciate).

The occuring error which I can't solve is the `pygame.error : No available audio device`

The issue was already asked, but I can't find an answer to it anywhere (I've truly been looking for one week). Does anyone know and could help me out find out what is the issue and how is it possible to fix it ?

Thanks a lot for your help and time,
Léo

Comment: Just curious, are you using the actual filepath or are you trying to call ´/home/filepath/filename.py´?

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your environment, i.e. operating system, library versions, sample code - [mcve]?

Comment: no, I am using an existing filepath (it was just for the example)

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 20.04, the python environment I work in is an Anaconda virtual environment used with Pycharm Community Edition.